# Is there any data that is preserved across versions of AWS S3 objects?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm using S3's versioning to store the potentially changing content of a file.

However, there is also a string (a name) that I want to be able to change but don't want versioned (so that if you retrieve an old version you only see the most recent version of this string (name)).

I tried using metadata and tags but they are all associated with a particular version of the object.

Comment: Could you please clarify your requirements? Do you wish to change the _contents_ with the string, or do you merely want the string attached as metadata _outside of the object_? It sounds like you will need to maintain your own database for this use-case.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I want to store the string as part of the object but I don't want it to be attached to a particular version. The metadata in S3 is attached to the version of the object, so that if you put another version of the same object it won't inherit the metadata of the previous version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it sounds like you do not want to modify the contents of the object.

Given your findings with versioning, then you will need to maintain that data yourself. You could either do it in a database (eg DynamoDB), or simply creating another object and store the information in the object or in its metadata.

For example, if you have object `foo`, you could create another object called `foo.name` that contains the information you wish to store against `foo`. After all, Amazon S3 is really just a big key-value data store.

Comment: It wasn't the answer I wanted to hear but I will probably have to move the names to DynamoDB or the whole thing as the contents are not large either.